# C# converting a VBA For Each loop to C# but gives compile error

Tags: c#, vba, foreach, office-automation

I am converting a Word VBA macro to a plugin in C#.

I have so far successfully refactored all statements, methods and properties in C#, but this one gives me a hard time:

```
For Each l In Application.Languages
    If InStr(LCase(l.NameLocal), LCase(Language)) > 0 Then
        Selection.LanguageID = l.ID
        Exit For
    End If
Next l
```

I have converted the above in C# as follows:

```
using Microsoft.Office;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
Word.Document oWordDoc = new Word.Document();
var Selection = oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection;
string strTgtLanguage = "Hungarian";

foreach (var item in oWord.Application.Languages)
{
          if (item.NameLocal.IndexOf(strTgtLanguage)>-1) 
//The error is  ---^  here on 'NameLocal'.
          {
              Selection.LanguageID = item.ID
//And here on 'ID' -----------------------^
              break;
          }
}
```

The compiler error for both instances is:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'NameLocal' and no extension method 'NameLocal' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is that I am doing wrong here? I thought the `foreach` statement properly declares the `object` from the collection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Speaking without any knowledge of the Office Interop libraries, I don't believe I see anything wrong here. Are you sure the `Application.Languages` in your C# version is the same as the one in your VB version? I see they're the same name, but are they the same type? That sounds like what's wrong. I see `oWord.Application.Languages` in C#, should that just be `Application.Languages`, for example?

Comment: one error I have found `Selection.LanguageID = l.ID` should be `Selection.LanguageID = item.ID`

Comment: That is, I don't think this is strictly an issue with the languages. You've got the correct syntax, and it's behaving as believe you expect it to. This would be a problem in VB as well, so I'd troubleshoot it the same way as you would have there. But yes, Mostafizur's comment is also correct--just a typo on the second one.

Comment: Also speaking without knowledge of Office Interop, but it's likely that `Application.Languages` returns an `IEnumerable`, not an `IEnumerable<SomeLanguageObject>`. If it's supposed to return a collection of a particular type, you can `Cast` it, i.e. `foreach (var item in oWord.Application.Languages.Cast<Language>()) { ... }`.

Comment: dee might be right. According to the documentation, `Languages` implements the non-generic `IEnumerable`, so an iterator would return `Object` instances. And, if I remember correctly, VB's Object is late-bound. Changing `var` to `Language` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `var item` with type name.

`foreach (var item in oWord.Application.Languages)` replace with
`foreach (Word.Language item in oWord.Languages)`

In the first case with `var` the variable `item` is of type `System.Object`.

Complete for-each using Linq could look like this:

```
foreach (Word.Language item in oWord.Languages.Cast<Word.Language>()
.Where(item => item.NameLocal.IndexOf(strTgtLanguage, StringComparison.Ordinal) > -1))
{
    selection.LanguageID = item.ID;
    break;
}
```

Or the for-each can be replace with e.g. `FirstOrDefault`:

```
Word.Language hungarian =
oWord.Languages.Cast<Word.Language>()
.FirstOrDefault(item => item.NameLocal.IndexOf(strTgtLanguage, StringComparison.Ordinal) > -1);

if (hungarian != null)
    selection.LanguageID = hungarian.ID;
```

Comment: isn't `var item` a local variable type inference so that the compiler would figure out the type based on the statement right side? In other words: isn't it still a strongly typed code?

Comment: @user3598756 Yes, but in the case of `foreach (var item in oWord.Application.Languages)`, the type on the right side is `object`, so `var` will be replaced by `object`. The statement `foreach (Word.Language item in oWord.Application.Languages)` does a cast. You can use `var` in `foreach (var item in oWord.Languages.Cast<Word.Language>())` because the cast has already been done on the right side.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I guess I could have verified that in VS but I wasn't (and still am not!) by it, and this `var` thing always blurs me...

Comment: @dee In fact without the cast of the IEnumerable on the right side, if I change the var to the strongly typed `Word.Language' it builds. But if I try to do the `Cast` it results in the compiler error "Foreach cannot operate on a 'method group'." So what works is `foreach (Word.Language item in oWord.Application.Languages)`.

Comment: Another question is which is considered better practice: the `foreach` or the `FirstOrDefault` with LINQ?

Comment: @ib11 IMO becasuse the `for-each` is enumerating only until first match is found and then it is breaked i would prefere to use `FirstOrDefault`. It is more readable. Inside of `FirstOrDefault` would probably be `for-each` as well so the performace should not be different.

Answer (score 2):

For your error code, first error seems to me that your `oWord.Application.Languages` does not actually return a collection field named `NameLocal`.

and the second one `Selection.LanguageID = l.ID` should be `Selection.LanguageID = item.ID`

Answer (score 1):

`Languages` is an IEnumerable so you'll need to declare the iteration variable explicitly.

If you use the `.Cast<>()` method of your IEnumerable, you could access the `.Any()` function to avoid writing the iteration loop yourself.

Both versions given below:

```
using wd = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

wd.Application oWord = new wd.Application();
wd.Document oWordDoc = new wd.Document();
wd.Selection oWordSelection = oWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection;

// foreach loop
foreach (wd.Language item in oWord.Languages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ID);
    if (item.NameLocal.IndexOf("Hungarian") > -1)
    {
        oWordSelection.LanguageID = item.ID;
        break;
    }
}

// linq
if (oWord.Languages.Cast<wd.Language>().Any(lang => lang.NameLocal.IndexOf("Hungarian") > -1))
    oWordSelection.LanguageID = wd.WdLanguageID.wdHungarian;
```

Comment: This gives a compiler error on the `foreach` line that `wd` is not a type or namespace.

Comment: I used `using wd = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`. Looking at your code I think you used `word`, so just replace `wd` with `word`.

Comment: Can you please just add this `using wd = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to the beginning of your code, so it is clear?

Comment: I accepted yours as you were the first one, even though @dee wrote the same thing.

Comment: Appreciate the thought, but I think @dee posted first. Whichever you accept, I hope it solved your question.

Comment: Wow, that is called fair, thanks for the heads up! I did vote you up though... :-)